# Click alert button with Selenium Builder

Tags: javascript, selenium

I am using the Selenium Builder Firefox plugin to generate my acceptance tests and I need to confirm certain actions that prompt a `confirm` dialog.

Is it possible to instruct Selenium Builder to click on the "OK" or the "Cancel" buttons?

Comment: try answerAlert or acceptAlert under the Misc heading, you will also see dismiss Alert which can be helpful

Answer (score 1):

Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();

//Getting alert text
       alert.getText();

alert.accept(); // Clicking OK Button

alert.dismiss(); // Clicking Cancel Button